# Debian can not connect to one specific wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, wpa-supplicant

I'm using following command to connect to any wifi network:

```
wpa_supplicant -c"/path/to/configfile" -Dwext -iwlp2s0
```

This command worked countless times and is also working right now. But I'm no longer able to connect to my cell phone's hotspot, beginning from a few days ago. My laptop can connect to any wifi network with above command, so there should be no problem with the command or the laptop. Other devices can connect to the phone's hotspot, so there should be no problem with the phone.

This is the output of `wpa_supplicant` when it successfully connects to a wifi network:

```
$ sudo killall wpa_supplicant 
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -c"./foo.conf" -Dwext -iwlp2s0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 00:1c:a8:f7:e8:4d (SSID='aea' freq=2462 MHz)
wlp2s0: Associated with 00:1c:a8:f7:e8:4d
wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:1c:a8:f7:e8:4d [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:1c:a8:f7:e8:4d completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

...and this is the unsuccessful connection attempt to my cell phone:

```
$ sudo killall wpa_supplicant 
wpa_supplicant: no process found
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -c"./bar.conf" -Dwext -iwlp2s0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

So there is no useful information in the outputs. How can I debug the issue?

Comment: Guess: Change in WLAN driver, or firmware version, or wpa_supplicant version, possibly without updateing the other. Note you can check your package history in `/var/log/dpkg*` and `/var/log/apt*`, so have a look at what you upgraded "a few days ago" ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details, but [this solved](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363514) the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrde
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo iw reg set DE
sudo sed -i 's/=.*/=DE/' /etc/default/crda
```